# css + how to have cells with a border and cells without a border

Tags: html, css

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/b484gLbj/2/)

I have got these cells that have borders:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
</div>
```

how do i make these cells not have a border?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" class="no-border"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" class="no-border"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" class="no-border"></div>
</div>
```

this is my css code that I have tried

```
    /* bootstrap */
    [class*="col-"] {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
        border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2);
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }       

        [class*="no-border"] {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: 0px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0);
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: May be you will find your solution. Please check this link:-https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the class names together in one `class` attribute separated by a space. This allows you to combine several CSS classes for one HTML element.

**eg**

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-border"></div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lypu09s1/)